# AngularJS : Why my watch is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to put a watch on a variable, so that if it's value changes I call the rest service and get updated count.

Here is how my code looks like

```
function myController($scope, $http) {

    $scope.abc = abcValueFromOutsideOfMyController;    

    $scope.getAbcCnt= function()
    {
        url2 = baseURL + '/count/' + $scope.abc;

        $http.get(url2).success(function (data) {
            $scope.abcCnt = data.trim();
        });
    };

    $scope.$watch('abc',getAbcCnt);
}
```

But, I get following error

```
ReferenceError: getAbcCnt is not defined
```

I am new to AngularJS, let me know if there is some fundamental concept I am missing and above is not possible to do.

This answer didn't help me
[AngularJS : Basic $watch not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664933/basic-watch-not-working-in-angularjs)

Comment: do you mean `$scope.$watch('abc',$scope.getAbcCnt);`

Comment: You've just asked a second, different question. Each post should be about a single question, not a whole problem. Suggestion: ask a new question and link to this. That makes the questions more useful and searchable to others.

Comment: Ok, I will move it in a separate one.

Comment: I moved it to a separate post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487102/using-angularjs-watch-to-get-drop-down-selected-item-not-working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reference it in the `$scope`.

```
$scope.$watch('abc', $scope.getAbcCnt);
```

If you were to declare your function without the `$scope` prefix your existing call would work, but you would not be able to access the function from the view.  If you don't need to access the function from the view, you can declare the function without the `$scope` and keep your existing `$watch` statement.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I was missing that. This error went away, but I get undefined for $scope.abc, I am going to update the question on how I set $scope.abc value

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/16487102/… is follow up issue

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant

```
$scope.$watch('abc',$scope.getAbcCnt);
```

Comment: Thanks! There is typo in AngularJS book $scope.$watch(' funding.startingEstimate', computeNeeded);

Green, Brad; Seshadri, Shyam (2013-04-08). AngularJS (Kindle Locations 665-668). O'Reilly Media. Kindle Edition.

Comment: @Watt I suspect that `computeNeeded` is not defined on the scope in that example.